# Are speaker wire output negative posts on receiver common-grounded?

Tags: grounding, speakers

I am buying a subwoofer (powered Sunfire HRS 12) that has high level inputs (bare speaker wire) and it says that it has it's negative posts joined (common-grounded) and that my receiver or amp also has to be common-grounded.

My question is, is this common to find in receivers? I have a Sony 2ch Receiver model STR-DH130 that I will be using with the subwoofer and I can't find this info on the manual.

I will check for continuity on the negative terminals on Left and Right speaker outputs on receiver, if there's continuity then is it safe to assume they are common-grounded?

thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Sony does not have a dedicated sub woofer output so you will need a sub-woofer that will pass through the sound to your  left and right speakers. Some subs only except a sub channel input and do not pass through left and right channels, many will except and pass along the right and left channels to the speakers,  meaning it will have **inputs** for left and right and **OUTPUTS** for left and right. .

As long as you wire the negative to negative  and positive to positive ( black to black and red to red ) you will be OK.

You did not say what sub-woofer model you are getting, I am not familiar with a subs that  sub that have "negative posts joined" Can you post the model? I found the following quote on [crutchfield.com](https://www.crutchfield.com/g_12300/Powered-Subwoofers.html) for the [polk PSW10](https://www.crutchfield.com/p_107PSW110B/Polk-Audio-PSW110-Black.html#Inputs%20and%20Outputs%20Notes) , i assume that is what you are referring to.

> "Speaker Level Input/Output: The sub-woofer has spring clips for the
>   speaker level inputs and outputs. The sub woofer's low-pass filter
>   sends bass frequencies (based on the setting of the filter) to the
>   sub-woofer. The speaker level inputs and outputs are shorted together,
>   so the output is not crossed over. You should set you receiver's front
>   speaker setting to Large."

Meaning you wire it as i stated and it passes the correct frequencies to the sub and the speakers.

Or you can use RCA cables from the video or md/tape ***audio out*** terminals on the receiver and go into the RCA Line in, left and right on the sub-woofer and wire your speaker into the out terminals on the sub.

Comment: edited my question by adding sub model, thanks!

Comment: the md/tape out signal from the receiver is not affected by volume control, so the sub would be at full volume all the time right?

Comment: @Alex Yes i forgot about that. looks like you will need to go from the video out to the line level input with RCA cable and connect your speakers directly to the sony.